# Changing a double pointer which is in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to change the x value in this code but I'm getting segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int **x;
} Type;

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    Type *type = malloc(sizeof(Type));
    type->x[0] = &a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: x doesnt point to anything. you need to malloc memory for it (as well as memory for 'type')

Comment: My bad sorry. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want an array of pointers to ints

```
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    Type *type = malloc(sizeof(Type));
    type->x = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 10)) ;// say we need 10
    type->x[0] = &a;
    return 0;
}
```